# Can I display text in SFML without setting a font?

Tags: c++, sfml, text

I'm trying to render text without setting a font.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string culoare;
int main()
{

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Window");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        sf::Text text;
            //atext.setFont();
            text.setString("HelloWorld");
            text.setCharacterSize(20);
            text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
            text.setColor(sf::Color::White);
            text.setPosition(0,0);
            window.draw(text);
            window.clear(sf::Color::Green);
            window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This just make a green window, but doesn't display text.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is you're clearing the screen after drawing the text. So this

```
        window.draw(text);
        window.clear(sf::Color::Green);
```

should be this

```
        window.clear(sf::Color::Green);
        window.draw(text);
```

If it still doesn't display anything, you definitely need to set a font!